# Will DBT read from materialised table or rerun SQL?

Tags: dbt

My new company use DBT and I'm struggling to find the answer to this question.

In my example, each model is set to **materialise as a table**.
If I have models that reference a previously run model and produce a DAG like this:
Query1 > Query2 > Query3 > Query 4.

Will this cause DBT to:
read from the **materialised table** of Query1 when it hits `{{ref ('Query1')}}` in Query2?
OR.
run all the SQL from Query1 again, and keep it in memory, when it hits `{{ref ('Query1')}}` in Query2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The former. dbt will replace `{{ ref('Query1') }}` with the fully-qualified name of the database relation that is materialized from the model whose name is `Query1`.

You can see the SQL that dbt actually executes in your `target` directory (inside your project directory), under `target/compiled/path/to/my/model` and/or `target/run/path/to/my/model`. If you do that for Query2, you'll see `{{ ref('Query1') }}` has been replaced with something like `"my_database"."my_schema"."Query1"`.

This is true only because you said that all of these models are materialized as tables. There are other materializations supported by dbt:

- Views: In this case, dbt will create a view for each model. Each downstream model will query the view, so the compiled SQL will similarly reference `"my_database"."my_schema"."Query1"` when you use `{{ ref('Query1') }}`. But under the hood, in order to execute that query, your database will be re-executing the SQL defined in `Query1`, since that is how views work
- Ephemeral: An "ephemeral" materialization isn't really a materialization! If you materialize `Query1` as `ephemeral`, and then `{{ ref('Query1) }}` in `Query2`, dbt will inject a CTE with the code from `Query1` into the compiled `Query2` query. That will look like:

```sql
-- Query1 is materialized as ephemeral
with "__dbt_cte_Query1" as (
    -- the code from the Query1 model file
)
-- your code from the Query2 model
select
    ...
from
    -- in your Query2 file, you used {{ ref('Query1') }} here
    "__dbt_cte_Query1"
...
```